# track by not working on select change value not getting selected

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I have written code like below

```
 <select ng-model="selectedseasId" ng-options="seas.seasInternalId as seas.seasName for seas in seass track by seas.seasInternalId"> </select>

$scope.selectedseasId = 3;
```

I have data like

```
var seass = [   {
        "seasInternalId" : 4,
       "seasName": "My Second seas"  
      },
         {
        "seasInternalId" : 3,
       "seasName": "My Second seas"  
      }
      ];
```

No value is getting selected in select box. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ng-options track by and select as are not compatible. See this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564)

Surely you don't need the track by ID as I suppose seasInternalId is unique, so `seas.seasInternalId as seas.seasName for seas in seass` should suffice and work.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use track by and select as in the ng-options expression.  From the documentation:

> Do not use **select as** and **track by** in the same expression. They are not
>   designed to work together.

Remove the track by part of the expression and it will work.

Documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-repeat instead of ng-option

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <select>
        <option ng-repeat="sea in seass">{{sea.seasName}}

      </select>

    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) 
    {
        $scope.seass = [
          {
            "seasInternalId" : 4,
           "seasName": "My Second seas 4"  
            },
            {
            "seasInternalId" : 3,
           "seasName": "My Second seas 3"  
          }
          ];

      $scope.seasInternalId = 4;

    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That's not at all the same thing. ng-options sets the ng-model for the select.